# Access External SD card on Samsung GT 2 7.0 (Verizon)

Tags: android, memory, external

I have a Verizon branded Samsung GT2 7.0 tablet that I am having trouble finding the EXTERNAL SD card.  Using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Only gets me the **INTERNAL SD card.**

I have tried to hard-code the path but that does not work either.  Any information on how to do this is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

When I enumerate all folders/files under internal card I get:

```
Music
Podcasts
Ringtones
Alarms
Notifications
Pictures
Movies
Download
DCIM
Documents
Android
peel
VaultService
Playlists
updates
```

None of these is the external card.

**Secondary question**

What's the point of the external sd card slot if you cannot access it?!

**EDIT 2**

I forgot to mention that my app is root on the tablet.  Should I not be able to get to it with root privileges?

Comment: I have already viewed that post and it does not help me.

Comment: Indeed it is a duplicate.  You need to implement one of the actual solutions offered there, not the mistaken answer that is so undeservedly upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

On devices that have both internal and external storage, the external storage is **usually** accessed from a subfolder of the internal storage path.

Android does not have an API to get the actual external path. It is up to the device manufacturer to implement it as they see fit.

http://www.kuffs.co.uk/index.php/when-is-an-sd-card-not-an-sd-card